I want to change the hud to the top right corner and have no problem with other resolutions
I would like to place the hud in the top corner and on the right, and that there would be no problem with other resolutions
local circleScale, sizeStroke = 50, 3
local iconScale = 25
local circleLeft, circleTop = circleScale + 30, y - circleScale - 20

addEventHandler('onClientResourceStart', resourceRoot, function()
    createCircle('bgHealth', circleScale, circleScale)
    createCircle('bgArmor', circleScale, circleScale)
    createCircleStroke('health', circleScale, circleScale, sizeStroke)
    createCircleStroke('armor', circleScale, circleScale, sizeStroke)

    hiddenComponents(false)
end)

addEventHandler('onClientResourceStop', resourceRoot, function()
    hiddenComponents(true)
end)

addEventHandler('onClientRender', root, function()
    drawItem('bgHealth', circleLeft, circleTop, tocolor(28, 28, 28, 170))
    drawItem('bgArmor', circleLeft + circleScale + 10, circleTop, tocolor(28, 28, 28, 170))

    drawItem('health', circleLeft, circleTop, tocolor(255, 255, 255))
    dxDrawImage(circleLeft + ((circleScale/2) - (iconScale/2)), circleTop + ((circleScale/2) - (iconScale/2)), iconScale, iconScale, 'assets/health.png')
    
    drawItem('armor', circleLeft + circleScale + 10, circleTop, tocolor(255, 255, 255))
    dxDrawImage((circleLeft + circleScale + 10) + ((circleScale/2) - (iconScale/2)), circleTop + ((circleScale/2) - (iconScale/2)), iconScale, iconScale, 'assets/armor.png')

    setSVGOffset('health', getElementHealth(localPlayer))
    setSVGOffset('armor', getPedArmor(localPlayer))
end)

I tried changing the number (circleScale + 30 and circleScale - 20) to another value, but in another resolution it is completely out of line with expectations.
